# Is O(mn) better than O((m+n)^2)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

The inputs to the algorithm are `m` and `n`.

The time complexity of my algorithm comes out to be `O(mn)`.

I have a benchmark algorithm that has a time complexity of `O((m+n)²)`.

Is my implementation better than the benchmark in terms of time complexity?

Comment: Is there a reason you think it is or isn't?

Comment: Do you really mean `O(m+n)^2.`and not `O((m+n)^2)`?

Comment: I think it is. Still need a double check as I am new to T.C analysis

Comment: @MrSmith42, it is indeed O((m+n)^2)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about theoretical computer science belong on [cs.se], whereas questions about math belong on [stats.se]. Neither topic is within our scope here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So many commenters and answerers wish to consider only the case when `m = n` or at least when they are related by a constant factor. That is not how this works.

Your algorithm is clearly faster when we hold either `m` or `n` constant; for example, if we restrict ourselves to the case `m = 1` then the complexity of your algorithm is `O(n)` whereas the alternative is `O(n^2)`, so yours is clearly better in this restricted case.

What we can say is that `(m+n)^2 = m^2 + n^2 + 2mn` is clearly `Ω(mn)` where `Ω` means this is a lower bound, and your algorithm is (asymptotically) always at least as good; i.e. there are no restricted cases where the other algorithm is asymptotically better than yours. But we do know there are restricted cases where yours is better. So, overall, yours is better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your implementation is better. Recall that (m+n)^2 = m^2 + n^2 + 2mn, so (m+n)^2 > mn

Comment: Well given that (m+n)^2 > mn , then if your implementation comes out to be O(mn) in terms of time complexity, then it will be better than a O((m+n)^2) implementation, because it will be faster

Comment: yes even I also felt that by regular algebra only we can easily derive ((m+n)^2)=m^2 + n^2 + 2mn.

Comment: @Adrien I somehow feel `O((m+n)^2)` is equal to `O(mn)`. So you cannot say it is better. I say if we compare it with `O()`.

Comment: For m=n both only differ by a factor of 3. So no difference in `O( )`-notation.

Comment: They are **not** equal. You cannot consider only the case where m = n.

Comment: @Afshin I do not agree. If n = O(m), then O((m+n)^2) = O(m^2). If m = O(n), then O((m+n)^2) = O(n^2). If neither n or m is dominated by the other, then you can definitely say that O(mn) implementation is better

Comment: If there is a benchmark with O((m+n)^2) complexity, this means that you can not neglect either n or m ( none is dominated by the other). Hence, you must keep both in your complexity, and you can definitively assert that the O(mn) complexity is better

Comment: @Adrien But the problem is comparison **asymptotically**. The algorithm with `O(mn)` always run better than `O((m+n)^2)`. But is it better asymptotically? I think answer is NO. They should be equal asymptotically. it is like when we ask if `O(1000n)` is better than `O(n)`.

Comment: I am adding to this, it is not defined that whether m=n or m!=n. Moreover, m and n both scale out and scale in. For my algorithm, I should at least assume m and n both are large values.

Comment: Then you must keep both in your complexity, and the O(mn) implementation is better, for sure

Comment: In short, it is kinda a "matching" algorithm where m=candidates and n=jobs. Now, as it is intuitive that both m and n should be large number and can not be neglected

Comment: @Afshin They are not equal asymptotically.

Comment: O(mn) captures the notion that having dramatically fewer jobs than candidates (or vice versa) makes the algorithm behave linearly in the larger group, while if the two groups are similar in size, the algorithm behaves quadratically. O((m+n)^2) can be interpreted as the algorithm behaving quadratically no matter which group is larger.

Comment: In a typical matching problem, `n` and `m` wouldn't represent the sizes of the two sets of nodes, though; they would represent the number of nodes and the number of edges *between* those nodes. Strictly speaking, `m = O(n^2)` is always true, but some algorithms may be more sensitive to the actual number of edges (fast on sparse graphs, slow on dense graphs), so the two values are treated distinctly.

Comment: This means it is safe to say that my implementation is better than the benchmark

Answer (score 0):

`O(mn)` is not in all cases better than `O((m+n)²)`.

---

Look at this case:

`O((m+n)²) = O(mn)`  if `m=O(n)`

for `m=O(n)` be can introduce a new variable (`c:= max(n,m)`)

```
O((m+n)²) = O(m² + 2mn + n²) 
           = O(c² + 2cc + c²=
           = O( 3* c²)
           = O(c²)

O(mn)      = O(cc) = O(c²)
```

So in the case that n and m only differ by about a constant both complexities are the same.

---

As mentioned in the comments **if not** `m=O(n)`
than `O(mn)` is better iff `O(n²) > O(nm)` or `O(m²) > O(mn)`.

---

**My Fazit:**
Depending on your definition of "better", you can say:
`O(mn)` is *never worse* than `O((m+n)²)`
or
`O(mn)` is *better* than `O((m+n)²)`

Comment: You cannot consider just the case where they differ by a constant; consider for example `m = sqrt(n)` which is in `O(n)`. In that case `O(mn) = O(n^1.5)` but `O((m+n)^2) = O(n^2)`.

Comment: I had similar thought, but wrote it completely bad.... <.<

Comment: The whole point of a complexity is having an idea of how it evolves with parameters changing. Here, obviously, it is expected that you keep both m and n in your complexity given that the benchmark mentions m and n. Hence, you can definitely say that the O(mn) implementation is better. You don't care wether n and m differ by a constant or not, you would still expect to display both m and n in your complexity

Comment: The whole point of having two variables `m` and `n` is to *avoid* assumptions like `m = O(n)`. If that were always true, we wouldn't bother with `O((m+n)**2)`; we'd just write `O(n**2)`.

Comment: @chepner: The whole point of my answer is that there exists a case where it is not better. So you cannot say it is better in all cases.

Comment: The whole point of using two variables is to convey the idea that the runtime is sensitive to the relative sizes of the two variables. In a graph problem, the number of edges is *always* O(n**2), but in practice that's not a *tight* bound. For example, the complexity of the [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft–Karp_algorithm) is given as O(sqrt(V)E), rather than O(V^2sqrt(V)), precisely because it is *useful* to note that the algorithm is sensitive to the number of edges actually present in the graph, not just the number of vertices.

Comment: Sure, there are cases where they are the same, but it's not useful to say that the algorithm is not better because of those cases. An algorithm that is *no worse* in the worst case but strictly better in other cases is, by any practical measure, a better algorithm.